# What is a general, portable way to silence commands in Linux?

Tags: bash, shell, command, portability, silent

Let's say I want to silence the command `type idonotexist`. Normally, it would output a message like the following:

```
bash: type: idonotexist: not found
```

How could a command like this be made to be silent in a portable way (i.e. in a way suited to common shells like Bash and zsh).

For an example of how it might be used, consider the command being used in a script that should display only the echo displays:

```
if type "idonotexist"; then
    echo "hello world"
else
    echo "install idonotexist"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help type` we know that

```
Exit Status:
Returns success if all of the NAMEs are found; fails if any are not found.
```

So you can redirect all the output to `/dev/null` --> `type <whatever> &>/dev/null` and rely on the exit status.

All together:

```
if type "idonotexist" &>/dev/null; then
    echo "hello world"
else
    echo "install idonotexist"
fi
```

Comment: This will still print anything `type "idonotexist"` sends to standard output even if the command fails, so if you want to suppress that as well, you'd use `if type "idonotexist" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null; then ...`.

Comment: @Ray good point. Updated using `&>/dev/null`, which is equivalent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bash (and apparently Zsh, too?) has a command-not-found handler but I don't think this is portable to other shells; certainly not portable in the POSIX sense.

It is used in e.g. Ubuntu to suggest installation of a missing package when you type a command which is not currently available, but is provided by a package you could install.

https://launchpad.net/command-not-found